# Parse.com error 100 on Cellular network

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

We have an iOS app and a Cloud Code backend in Parse. The cloudcode is working fine using WiFi connection but, when the cellular network is active, I get a 'Operation could not be completed - Error code 100' in the iOS app. Of course the cellular network is correctly working and I have no internet problem. There is something to specifically setUp in Parse TO run in cellulare network ?

Thanks
Dario

Comment: Add some code, check the status code [definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).